# Reflection for composite property names

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-3.5

I have a `Dictionary<string, object>` which holds a property name as string and it's value as object. I also have a `Bind` method extension which, through reflection, sets that propery name with its corresponding value:

```
public static T Bind<T>(this T @this, 
                        Dictionary<string, object> newValues, 
                        params string[] exceptions) where T : class
{
    var sourceType = @this.GetType();
    foreach (var pair in newValues.Where(v => !exceptions.Contains(v.Key)))
    {
        var property = sourceType.GetProperty(pair.Key, 
                                              BindingFlags.SetProperty | 
                                              BindingFlags.Public      | 
                                              BindingFlags.Instance);
        var propType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? 
                       property.PropertyType;
        property.SetValue(@this, (pair.Value == null) ? null : 
                                 Convert.ChangeType(pair.Value, propType), null);
    }
    return @this;
}
```

For instance, consider a class like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string   Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Everything runs fine, except when I got a class with a property name of another object, like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string   Name    { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date    { get; set; }
    public Address  Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}
```

So, if I try to send a `Name` property name, ok, but I got problems with composite property names, like `Address.PostalCode`.

Can you advise a way to handle that situation?

**EDIT #1:**

To summarize the problem: calling `sourceType.GetProperty("Name", ...)` in the context of a `User` class instance correctly allows to set its value, but it doesn't work using a `sourceType.GetProperty("Address.PostalCode", ...)` in same instance.

**EDIT #2:**
A more complete example should be:

```
var user   = new User{ Address = new Address() };
var values = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    { "Name"              , "Sample"       },
    { "Date"              , DateTime.Today },
    { "Address.PostalCode", "12345"        } // Here lies the problem
}
user.Bind(values);
```

Comment: What is the problem? What happens and what do you want to happen instead?

Comment: I just added more info, @fejesjoco

Comment: You're saying that like it's a small fixable bug in your program that a multipart binding path doesn't work, but it's a completely new feature that you're asking for.

Comment: @fejesjoco, maybe another way to say it is: how can I recursively solve that property bind problem by using reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it identifying if the property name have a period and recurring it:

```
public static T Bind<T>(this T @this,
                Dictionary<string, object> newValues,
                params string[] exceptions) where T : class
{
    var sourceType = @this.GetType();
    var binding = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;
    foreach (var pair in newValues.Where(v => !exceptions.Contains(v.Key)))
    {
        if(pair.Key.Contains("."))
        {
            var property = sourceType.GetProperty(
                           pair.Key.Split('.').First(),
                           binding | BindingFlags.GetProperty);
            var value = property.GetValue(@this, null);
            value.Bind(new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { 
                    String.Join(".", pair.Key.Split('.').Skip(1).ToArray()),
                    pair.Value
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            var property = sourceType.GetProperty(pair.Key, 
                           binding | BindingFlags.SetProperty);
            var propType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ??
                           property.PropertyType;
            property.SetValue(@this, (pair.Value == null) ? null :
                     Convert.ChangeType(pair.Value, propType), null);
        }
    }
    return @this;
}
```

Usage:

```
var user   = new User {Address = new Address{ User = new User() }};
var values = new Dictionary<string, object>()
{
    {"Name", "Sample"},
    {"Date", DateTime.Today},
    {"Address.PostalCode", "12345"},
    {"Address.User.Name", "Sub Sample"}
};

user.Bind(values);

public class User
{
    public string   Name     { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date     { get; set; }
    public Address  Address  { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public User   User       { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that `Convert.ChangeType` only works for objects implementing `IConvertible`. Thus, I'd just add a check, and only use `Convert.ChangeType` if `pair.Value` has a type that implements IConvertible. Furthermore, afaik Convert does not use overloaded conversion operators, so you can save this check whenever pair.Value is not a struct, i.e.

```
object value;
if (pair.Value == null) {
    value = null;
} else {
    value = pair.Value.GetType().IsStruct ? Convert.ChangeType(pair.Value, propType) : pair.Value;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many binding engines out there, [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx), [winforms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in the core .NET and who knows how many others, you can check out all their source codes and documentation about their syntax.

Let's see the most simple case. Let's say that the variable X holds an object and you have the binding expression "A.B.C". Let's split up the binding path, the first part is "A". So you use reflection to get the property named "A" in X, and you put that other object into X. Now comes the second part, "B", so let's find a property named "B" in (the new) X. You find that, and put that into X. Now you get to the final part, "C", and now you can either read or write that property in X. The point is that you don't need recursion or anything, it's just a simple loop, you iterate over the parts of the binding expression, evaluate them, and you keep the current object in the same variable.

But the fact is that it can get much more complex than that. You could ask for array indexing, like "A.B[2].C". Or what if you have a path "A.B", and X.A is null, what do you do? Instantiate X.A, but what if it lacks a public parameterless constructor?

I want you to see that it can be a very complex problem. You have to specify a syntax and rules, and then implement that. You didn't specify in your question the exact syntax and rules you want to use. And if it happens to be more than the simple case I mentioned above, then the solution could be too lengthy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think this have a very complex scenario, at least I don't need it.

I'm using RadGrid (Telerik) which allows to use a `<%# Bind("") %>` syntax an later call a `ExtractValuesFromItem` method to get a `Dictionary<string, object>` as return. As ASP.NET can solve a `Bind("Address.PostalCode")`, I just want to achieve same functionality to update my custom object properties with values collected on UI.